# Display lines in msgbox with spaces between them

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to display some lines in my code via the `Msgbox` function. And in order to make it more readable I need lines to be separated with spaces between them. Is it possible ?

Of course I used `& Chr(10) & _` to make a new line. But what about spaces between them - no idea.

Comment: How many spaces? If one, you can use `your_string & " " & your_string`.

Comment: `& Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _`   Or define `Const LF2 As String = vbLf & vbLf` then use `LF2` in your code.

Comment: If you want to 'create columns', `vbTab` might come in handy.

Comment: alright will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/force-new-line-msgbox-message), you can use:

```
MsgBox "TextA" & vbCrLf & "TextB"
```

to "force" a Line Break. The result is:

[image: Result Image]

Comment: Thanks, how i can make a space between these two lines wider ?

Comment: `MsgBox "TextA" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "TextB"`

Comment: @Yega If this answered your question, please "checkmark" it to show others it solved your problem.